# Masstransit IReceiveObserver can not get message body

Tags: c#, masstransit, observers

I am trying to get a specific info from all the messages consumed by my service, and I do not want to repeat the same code inside each consumer I have.

So I created a class that implements IReceiveObserver and inside   `public Task PreReceive(ReceiveContext context)` I am trying to get the message body, except that I could not.

```
  public Task PreReceive(ReceiveContext context)
        {
            var body = context.GetBody();
            return null;
        }
```

I am assuming that body will contain the message body, so I am trying to deserialize it using:

```
   public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return o;
        }
var Deserialized =(GeneralMessageType) DeserializeFromStream((MemoryStream)body);
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'The input stream
>   is not a valid binary format.

Is this the correct way of achieving what I need? I think I am following the right approach but I have an issue in extracting the message body.

**Update:**

Message body using `Console.WriteLine("{0}", (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd());`:

> {\r\n  \"messageId\":
>   \"01110000-5d1b-0015-b7c9-08d5479e73b2\",\r\n  \"correlationId\":
>   \"da197981-a10e-43a9-a53b-67b7a3261511\",\r\n  \"conversationId\":
>   \"01110000-5d1b-0015-80d3-08d5479e73a6\",\r\n  \"sourceAddress\":
>   \"queue URL",\r\n  \"destinationAddress\": \"receiverURL",\r\n 
>   \"messageType\": [\r\n    \"urn:message:MessageType"\r\n  ],\r\n 
>   \"message\": {\r\n    \"correlationId\":
>   \"da197981-a10e-43a9-a53b-67b7a3261511\",\r\n    \"Id\":
>   \"62d2bfff-7e20-4b51-b431-7d46e44abfc0\",\r\n    \"Name\":
>   \"'''yry'''\",\r\n    \"Code\": \"ryryyy\",\r\n    \"isActive\":
>   true,\r\n    \"username\": \"username\",\r\n    \"password\":
>   \"*****\",\r\n    \"isUserActive\": true\r\n  },\r\n  \"headers\":
>   {},\r\n  \"host\": {\r\n    \"machineName\": \"myMachine\",\r\n
>   \"processName\": \"w3wp\",\r\n    \"processId\": 4568,\r\n
>   \"assembly\": \"MassTransit\",\r\n    \"assemblyVersion\":
>   \"3.5.7.1082\",\r\n    \"frameworkVersion\": \"4.0.30319.42000\",\r\n 
>   \"massTransitVersion\": \"3.5.7.1082\",\r\n
>   \"operatingSystemVersion\": \"Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.16299.0\"\r\n 
>   }\r\n}"

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to perform your serialization? My guess is that you are not using `BinaryFormatter` when serializing, and therefore you are getting this error when you try to deserialize.

Comment: I am not performing the serialization, Masstransit is, I am sending the message without serialization

Comment: What does the contents of your `MemoryStream` look like if you just capture it and write it out? Try outputting using: `Console.WriteLine("MemoryStream Content: {0}", (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd());`

Comment: question updated

Comment: "PreReceive" sounds like an event that triggers before something is received. Perhaps the body isn't available at this time?

Comment: no, it is available

Comment: Look at how MassTransit deserializes it and you'll be there: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Serialization/JsonMessageDeserializer.cs#L52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

As you can see in question body    `context.GetBody();` gives a json containing Host info, Headers, and Message body in addition to a few other attributes.

What I did is removing "\r\n"s and replacing \" with " and then going 
to https://jsonutils.com/, paste the resulting Json and it will convert it to the classes you should deserialize to.

The thing is body contains much more info than the message sent, all of them added by masstransit and rabbitmq.

```
 public class Message
{
    //Message attributes
}

public class Headers
{
}

public class Host
{
    public string machineName { get; set; }
    public string processName { get; set; }
    public int processId { get; set; }
    public string assembly { get; set; }
    public string assemblyVersion { get; set; }
    public string frameworkVersion { get; set; }
    public string massTransitVersion { get; set; }
    public string operatingSystemVersion { get; set; }
}

public class TotalMessage
{
    public string messageId { get; set; }
    public string correlationId { get; set; }
    public string conversationId { get; set; }
    public string sourceAddress { get; set; }
    public string destinationAddress { get; set; }
    public IList<string> messageType { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
    public Headers headers { get; set; }
    public Host host { get; set; }
}
```

for deserializing you can use:

```
  public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return o;
        }

 var body = context.GetBody();
 var totalMessage= JsonDeserializer<TotalMessage>((MemoryStream)body);
```

To get the message body: `totalMessage.message`

**Update:**

Of course you can deserialize to only the message body by something like:

```
public class TotalMessage
{
    public Message message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's one way to do it I guess. Or you could just look at my other comment.

Comment: will update it when I have time, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

So you do not need to bother with the `BinaryFormatter`. Instead you should use `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractJsonSerializer` as the content of your stream is coming through as JSON. You can do that with the following code:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MassTransit));
MassTransit obj = (MassTransit)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

This is assuming the object you are trying to deserialize is of the type `MassTransit`. If it is not, then simply replace that with whatever class you are trying to deserialize an instance of.

You could make this a generic method like this:

```
public static T JsonDeserializer<T>(MemoryStream strm)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.ReadObject(strm);
}
```

And simply call that wherever you want to deserialize an object from a JSON stream.

Comment: I am getting the following System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'The data contract type 'MessageType' cannot be deserialized because the required data members '<Code>k__BackingField, <Id>k__BackingField, <Name>k__BackingField, <CorrelationId>k__BackingField, <IsActive>k__BackingField, <IsUserActive>k__BackingField, <Password>k__BackingField, <UserEmail>k__BackingField, <Username>k__BackingField' were not found.'

Comment: Are you certain you are deserializing to the correct type? Is `MessageType` the correct class?

Comment: Well, the error you are getting is telling you that the content you are receiving does not match that type due to expected members not being present. Do you have the class definition (.Net code) for `MessageType` available? It may not be defined properly. Each member should be decorated with the `[DataMember]` attribute, and the class with `[DataContract]`.

Comment: the Json contains extra info than the messageType, because Masstransit adds them to the message, does that make difference?

Comment: When you add `DataMember` attributes are you ensuring that you are naming them the same as how they are being passed? I see in your json data that you have members named with different cases compared to what it seems your deserializer is looking for. I.e. your class member names are not the same case as your json members. Your class should define them to match: `[DataMember(name = "username")] public string Username { get; set; }`